# Decipher the Picture

Tags: visual

[image: Cipher]

Hidden in this image is a word or phrase. What is it?

Hint #1:

> Almost all of the intersections and all of the dots are on a certain lattice. This lattice is important.

Hint #2:

> The lattice is 5x15. Its columns correspond to letters.

Comment: If it's a phrase, does each "part" of the picture mean a different word?

Comment: @Doge I'll start giving hints if nobody gets it for a while, but not yet.

Comment: Where is BmyGuest when you need him?

Comment: Anyone: What (free?) software can I use to rotate the 3 pics around their respective dots?

Comment: (Thanks Google) You can use LunaPic: http://www181.lunapic.com/editor/?action=rotate. It's an online image editor. Download the above picture and cut it into 3 parts with the dots at the center, then use LunaPic to rotate them.

Comment: @Doge Thanks Doge but i want to rotate the pictures around the dot while keeping the others in their same relative positions. I wanna be able to highlight a square area and rotate around whatever point I want, namely, that pic's dot.

Comment: @JLee paint.net will do that. I tried the same thing yesterday. Select the area you want, move the cursor to just outside of the box and you'll see the rotate handle come up. After rotating at least once, there will be a small circle with an X in the middle. Click and drag that to where you want to define the point of rotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's

> CONGRATULATIONS.

Explanation:

> Wherever there's a mark on a lattice point (either dot or corner/intersection/line), it's interpreted as a 1; where there isn't, it's interpreted as a 0. Read down the columns to get 5-bit binary, then convert to letters (A is 1, B is 2) to get the answer.